# C# : modify form control from a class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance, controls

I have Form and Class like that :

```
namespace ALTER_Control
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ALTER A = new ALTER();
            A.ALTER();
        }
    }

    public class ALTER
    {
        public Form1 F;
        public void ALTER()
        {
            F.TextBox1.Text="I Altered That";
        }
    }
}
```

So i try to call ALTER() to change the textbox1 value in Form1 but i get that error :

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

That happens only if i am accessing or modifying the Form1 Controls.

And by the way i set textbox1 modifier to public

So , finally i`d like to change the control value without getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the reference to the form. Like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ALTER A = new ALTER();
            A.F = this;
            A.ALTER();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why does your `ALTER` class (which isn't a great class name either) have to know about your form?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ALTER A = new ALTER();
        this.TextBox1.Text = A.ALTER();
    }
}

[...]

public class ALTER
{
    public String ALTER()
    {
        // Do your thing

        return "I Altered That";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Separation of responsibilities is a fundamental practice of every OOP. The class ALTER should do it's work and present results to the UI interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use these lines of code:

```
    ALTER A = new ALTER();
    A.F = this ;
    A.ALTER();
```